# Is there any need for GCC's .fini section in a bare-metal microcontroller application?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, ld, bare-metal, linker-scripts

From what I can find, .fini is used for the destruction of static storage duration objects after `main` returns. In a typical bare-metal application, `main` does not return. Is there any reason not to simply remove these symbols from the linker script?

Comment: not sure why it would be needed in the first place, before, during, or after main...in a baremetal microcontroller application...but it depends highly on the libraries you use and their requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In a typical bare-metal application, main does not return.

`main()` can indeed return to the startup code, which can be customized to do something after the application exited, e.g. restart it, cut the power, or start a firmware update. It that case, static destructors can be needed.

> Is there any reason not to simply remove these symbols from the linker script?

If `main()` never returns and `exit()` is never called, then of course you can remove these symols, but then the library startup will miss them, and you'll have to provide a function to override the library function that iterates through `__fini_array`.

If you are using `newlib`, you can recompile it with `--enable-lite-exit` to omit all `fini` stuff.